# Firebase Cloud Messaging API Console - Targeting users

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM console to send push messages to the users. Until now I am targetting using User Segments through which I can filter users based on language. But now I need to allow users to subscribe or unsubscribe to the type of alerts they can receive. So I am exploring the option **Topics**. But now from firebase console I can either target users based on User Segments or Topics.

I want to be able to use Topics with the options I can get in User Segments(where I can filter based on language). Is there a way to make this possible?

Thanks,
Sindhu

Answer (score 1):

Segments can't be targeted with topics.  Segments are populated by data collected by Firebase Analytics, and don't identify individual devices.  Topics are just names that you make up, and the names must match between the device and server.

You will need to find a way to match up users in a segment to the topic that you create for that segment.  You could try to use Remote Config to give clients the name of a topic that matches their segment, then use FCM to subscribe to that topic.